# What is a way to determine if a var is an elementFinder object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, protractor

What is a way to determine if a var is an elementFinder object?
The way I'm doing it now is to check if ".getText()" is part of the object. But I want to see if there's a better way.

```
 if (!el.getText) { 
     throw "The supplied parameter is not an elementFinder and needs to be."; 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
if(el.constructor !== elementFinder){
    throw "The supplied parameter is not an elementFinder and needs to be."; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator.

```
if( ! (el instanceof elementFinder) ){
    throw "The supplied parameter is not an elementFinder and needs to be."; 
}
```